# Sharepoint : copy data from one list to another by end of week

Tags: list, data

We have requirement to generate weekly and monthly trend charts in Excel based on a list from SharePoint. There is no option to capture date in this list.

We thought of copying data from one list to another list on a weekly basis (and by adding new column to this list as a date of shipping). This would allow us to generate weekly/monthly trend charts.

Is there a way to copy/automate this data shipping from one list to other by end of week?

Answer (score 1):

You can create timer job , which will run weekly or monthly as per your requirement. You can find multiple sites describing how to create timer jobs like [Link1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Creating-80ab3424)
[Link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh528519(v=office.14).aspx)

You can write your business logic for Copying list item to another list in Execute method.
[This link will help with the business logic](http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-sharepoint-list-items-from-one-site-to-another-programmatically/)

Hope this will solve your problem.